# Setting a string with the DocumentText in Forms.WebBrowser in Mono

Tags: .net, mono, browser

I'm porting a .NET application to Mono 2.6.7 and I'm having problems with a the web browser control. I made a separate project to try and recreate the issue.

I'm doing this:

```
public class Gui : System.Windows.Forms.Form {      
    public Gui() {
        var browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();            
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        browser.DocumentText = "<html><body>1234</body></html>";
    }
}
```

And it fails with this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Mono.Mozilla.DOM.HTMLElement.set_OuterHTML (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.set_DocumentText (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:set_DocumentText (string)
  at WebBrowserTest.Gui..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) WebBrowserTest.Gui:.ctor ()
  at WebBrowserTest.SharpWiredMain..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at WebBrowserTest.SharpWiredMain.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have tried many different things and I think I got it to work with the DocumentStream but I would really prefer if I could use the DocumentText property.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems as if this is a Mono bug already https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=640411 Too bad :(

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made a temporary fix to this bug:
code below:
Instead of using the WebBrowser in your code, find and replace with MyWebBrowser derivative that you created.

```
public class MyWebBrowser : WebBrowser
{


    public MyWebBrowser()
    {
        this.Disposed += new EventHandler(this_Disposed);
    }

    void this_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ms != null)
        {
            ms.Close();
            ms.Dispose();
        }            
    }

    private MemoryStream ms = null;

    private string _documentText = "";
    public new string DocumentText
    {
        get 
        {
            return _documentText;
        }
        set
        {
            try
            {
                _documentText = value;
                byte[] documentData = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(_documentText);
                ms = new MemoryStream(documentData);
                this.DocumentStream = ms;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try geckofx?

https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx/wiki/Home